# Hello I can't seem to figure out why my program isn't working

Tags: java

The program is to calculate the total price for meat but I keep getting the output of $.68 instead of $10.89, any help would be greatly appreciated. While i'm sure it's most likely a error with the last println statement any help would be useful.

```
 /**********************************************************************
Program: Deli.java
Description: Computes the price of a deli item given the weight (in ounces) 
        and the price per pound.
***********************************************************************/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Deli
{
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The function main reads in the price per pound of a deli item
and the number of ounces of a deli item then computes the total price 
and prints a "label" for the item that includes the unit price (per pound),
the weight and total price.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

public static void main (String[] args)
{
final double OUNCES_PER_POUND = 16.0;
double pricePerPound;   // price per pound
double weightOunces;    // weight in ounces
double weight;      // weight in pounds
double totalPrice;      // total price for the item
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Declare money as a NumberFormat object and use the
getCurrencyInstance method to assign it a value.
Declare fmt as a DecimalFormat object and instantiate
it to format numbers with at least one digit to the left of the
decimal and the fractional part rounded to two digits.
Prompt the user and read in each input. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
NumberFormat format1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DecimalFormat format2 = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System. out. println ("Welcome to the CS Deli! ! \n ");
System.out.print ("Enter the price per pound of your item: ");
pricePerPound = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print ("Enter the weight (ounces): ");
weightOunces = scan.nextDouble();

// Convert ounces to pounds and compute the total price
weight = weightOunces / OUNCES_PER_POUND;
totalPrice = pricePerPound * weight;

// Print the unit price, weight, and total price using the formatting objects.
// Format the weight in pounds and use the money format for the prices.
System.out.println("\nUnit Price: " + format1.format(pricePerPound) + " per pound");
System.out.println("\nWeight: " + format2.format(weightOunces) + " pounds");
System.out.println("\nTotal Price: " + format1.format(totalPrice));
}
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs and actual outputs?

Comment: Well I can see you're printing `weightOunces` as "pounds" for one thing.

Comment: The inputs are $4.25 for the unit price, and 2.56 pounds.

Answer (score 0):

`"The inputs are $4.25 for the unit price, and 2.56 pounds."`

I think you're a little confused here as to how your application is expecting its input. The prompts ask for ***The price per pound***:

```
Enter the price per pound of your item: 4.25
```

and then asks to enter  ***The weight in ounces***:

```
Enter the weight (ounces): 2.56
```

Again, it asks to enter in **ounces** not pounds. The code then takes this **ounces** input (2.56) and converts it to pounds which ends up being about **0.16** pounds. Well, I suppose **0.16** pounds of the item which is priced at $**4.25** per pound will cost you **$0.68** dollars (or just 68 cents).

If you really wanted to purchase 2.56 pounds of the item then you should have supplied `40.96` (2.56 * 16) in the ounces prompt.

As @JohnBayko has already so graciously pointed out, you are displaying the wrong value in your output from this code line:

```
System.out.println("\nWeight: " + format2.format(weightOunces) + " pounds");
```

It should be your conversion value displayed not what was entered:

```
System.out.println("\nWeight: " + format2.format(weight) + " pounds");
```

Comment: Even after making this correction the output still results in $.68 instead of the value im required to get of $10.89

Comment: Well then, your still entering 2.56 ounces. Try entering 40.96 ounces.

Comment: Did this click with you yet?